# Suddenly unable to boot, stuck at 'Stopping save udev log'

Tags: boot, 13.10

Everything was normal until a while back, but I just booted my computer and I'm getting the screen below. It hangs/freezes here, and I've no clue what to do. Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can happens because your x-windows is not getting suffecient space to blotup

press

```
ctrl+alt+f2
```

Then loggin with your user name and password in cli mode 
type

> df -h

and go to the most space consuming ditectory and remove all unnessasary files and folders
and then
type

> init 6

to restart your system

hope this could solve your problam

Comment: Nope this wasn't the issue. Any other ideas?